# Add browser bookmark to bookmark browser

Tags: bookmarks, navigation, web-browser

What I mean is, can I add a URL to my Emacs bookmarks, such that selecting the bookmark runs the URL through `browse-url`?

**Desired behavior**

What I would like is a `bookmark-set-url` function that prompts for a `url`, say `emacs.stackexchange.com`. Then when I run `bookmark-jump`, `emacs.stackechange.com` appears in my bookmarks, and selecting it runs `(browse-url "emacs.stackexchange.com")`.

This is analogous to `bookmark-set`, which sets a bookmark that points at the current location.

Is this behavior—or something similar—available in Emacs? If not is it possible to augment `bookmarks` (or `bookmarks+`) to support it?

The reason I want this is that `bookmark-jump` feels like a general purpose targeted navigation command. Browser URLs feel like an extension of that idea, despite the fact that they switch to a different application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following seems working from here (I don't use the Bookmarks feature, and I ain't familir with its protocol.), I tested it with:

```
M-x your-bookmark-set-url https://example.com
M-x bookmark-jump https://example.com
```

```el
(defun your-bookmark-set-url (url)
  (interactive "sBookmark URL: ")
  (if (assoc url bookmark-alist)
      (user-error "%s is already bookmarked" url)
    (push `(,url . ((handler . ,(lambda (bookmark)
                                  (browse-url (car bookmark))))))
          bookmark-alist)))
```

Comment: I tried this approach and it works, but then I can't see my bookmarks list again. I ended up instead for installing Bookmark+. Its not quite as hard as the documentation makes it sound. Then you can just call ```bmkp-url-target-set```.